# How do I temporarily block a packet being sent from my computer to an ip address?

Tags: python, networking, packet

Ok so I am trying to block a specific packet on my computer that I captured using wireshark from being sent to an ip address. It is UDP protocol. So, how would I accomplish this with python?

Edit: I am currently on Windows 10

Comment: Packets are sent and received with the help of your operating system, so you'll need to use its OS-specific interfaces to control its firewall/filtering mechanism; to my knowledge there is not a platform-independent firewall control module for Python that can abstract this away. Please [edit] your post to specify which specific OS you're interested in.

Comment: I just updated it, thanks.